# javascript json create parent element for each current element

Tags: javascript, json, element, parent-child, parent

I've got the following JSON:

```
{
  "BTC": "0",
  "XCP": "0",
  "NOBL": "0",
  "USDE": "0",
  "SOC": "0",
  "KDC": "0",
  "DOGE": "0.00000001"
}
```

What i need to obtain is:

```
[
 { "Coin": "BTC",
    "Value": "0"
 },
 { "Coin": "XCP",
    "Value": "0"
 },
 { "Coin": "NOBL",
    "Value": "0"
 },
 { "Coin": "USDE",
    "Value": "0"
 },
 { "Coin": "SOC",
    "Value": "0"
 },
 { "Coin": "KDC",
    "Value": "0"
 },
 { "Coin": "DOGE",
    "Value": "0.00000001"
 }
]
```

I don't know exactly how to achieve this...i suppose i need to use a foreach key function but i don´t know exactly how to solve this...
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "for (var x in y)" type of loop to enumerate through the source collection:

```
var source = {
  "BTC": "0",
  "XCP": "0",
  "NOBL": "0",
  "USDE": "0",
  "SOC": "0",
  "KDC": "0",
  "DOGE": "0.00000001"
};

var destination = [];

for (var type in source) {
    destination.push({
        Coin: type,
        Value: source[type]
    });
}
```

Comment: Lol, you beat me to it.

Comment: ha, was just about to paste some code when this came up.